# Можно ли как-то пометить использование в коде метода или свойства из ссылочной библиотеки?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Пишу код плагина для зарубежного софта. Соответственно, чтобы получить доступ к API этого софта, подключаю ссылками его DLL. API местами кривоват. При этом, разработчики софта сильно инертны и внесения исправлений в API от них можно ждать годами. А работать как-то надо. Поэтому, для вызова некоторых методов и свойств приходится делать обёртки, чтобы эту кривость пофиксить. Но хочется как-то на уровне решения или проекта каким-то способом пометить этот кривой метод или свойство, чтобы при его использовании выскакивало предупреждение типа "метод кривой, есть обёртка такая-то - используй её". То есть, как будто им добавили атрибут Obsolete в их DLL. Есть ли такая возможность в .NET, C# или Visual Studio?